# Slice the data for each unique id in python

Tags: python, loops, pandas, slice

```
id       val
a         1
a         1
a         2  
a         2
a         1
a         2
a         2
b         1 
b         1
b         2 
b         2 
b         1
b         1
b         2
b         2 
b         3
```

I am trying to slice the data for each `id` and based on length of `val`. I want the data to be sliced for every 4 rows

for id `a` the index values for data slicing are `[0,4]`
for id `b` the index values for data slicing are `[7,11,15]`

I can manually do it for each index inbound and outbound values

for example

```
 df2=df[0:3]
 remaining code

 df2a=df[4:6]
 remaining code

 df2b = df2.append(df2a, ignore_index=True)
```

I know this is not a good programming practice and since I am still novice to python, I need your help to simplify this through looping. I have more than million records in my dataframe.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. ```based on length of val``` isn't specific enough - what criteria are you using?  How did you *compute* [0,4] for a and [7,11,15] for b?

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear. Here I will change the `value` of each `id` based on some criteria - for that I need to divide the `DataFrame` for every four rows. The desired output is a `DataFrame` for each `id` with four rows.

Comment: [0,4] for a and [7,11,15]  for b is manual calculation - these are `Index` values of each 'id' of a and b in my example

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `subgroup` variable which denotes a different group for every four rows and then you can group by both `id` and `subgroups` variable and analyze each group separately:

```
df['subgroups'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount() // 4

for _, g in df.groupby(['id', 'subgroups']):
    print(g)

#  id  val  subgroups
#0  a    1          0
#1  a    1          0
#2  a    2          0
#3  a    2          0

#  id  val  subgroups
#4  a    1          1
#5  a    2          1
#6  a    2          1

#   id  val  subgroups
#7   b    1          0
#8   b    1          0
#9   b    2          0
#10  b    2          0

#   id  val  subgroups
#11  b    1          1
#12  b    1          1
#13  b    2          1
#14  b    2          1

#   id  val  subgroups
#15  b    3          2
```